# Powershell script for Test-path is not working

Tags: windows, powershell, file, powershell-3.0

I am passing a list of folders comma separated in the first parameter. The script works fine on windows 2012 server but does not working on windows 2008. This script on 2008 works if a single folder is passed but with multiple folders it does not enters the if condition with `testpath`

> Param1:
> C:\inetpub\logs,C:\temp\Logs\Management,E:\IIS-Logs,E:\VerifyLogs\FraudChecker
>
> Param2: test

```
param([String] $LogClearDownPaths,[String] $ServerType)
    
    
    $IISLogPath = $LogClearDownPaths.Split(",")
   
    foreach($path in $IISLogPath)
    {     
          if (Test-Path -Path $path)
          {
            Write-Host "testing is done here"
          }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us _the exact command and arguments_ you're using.

Comment: The comma is an accepted character in a file or folder name..

Comment: Why are you passing an array of paths to a `string` parameter instead of making the parameter a `string[]` parameter that will take multiple paths?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Powershell 3.0 on the 2008 server I believe you need to use the following syntax:

`$IISLogPath = $LogClearDownPaths -Split ","`

I'm not 100% sure because I can't find the relevant documentation but I think using $var.Split() is unique to Powershell 5.0 and up.